# Small voltage reduction

Tags: voltage

I have a home built radio which can take a voltage range of 2.2V to 3.6V.

I wish to use a Lion battery that is 3.87 volts when fully charged.

Can I sensibly reduce the voltage to 3.6 simply?

I have been told this can be done with a diode.

Comment: If you add a bunch of diodes in series, each will "eat" about 0.7V when forward-biased.

Comment: Thanks, could you explain what you mean by a bunch of diodes and how many mAs would be used. thank you for your help

Comment: You can get diodes that will eat about 0.4v instead of 0.7v, check the datasheet, for example, https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/MBR2045CT-D.PDF

Answer (score 2):

> I have been told this can be done with a Diode.

Well, yes, but.  A small-signal silicon diode will drop around 0.7 volts *always* -- which means that when your battery is almost fully discharged, your radio will still be getting 0.7V less than the battery.

It would be much better to get a voltage **regulator**.  3.3V is a common voltage, and it should work well with your stated voltage range.  You want to get a true low dropout voltage regulator.  For a while, manufacturers were calling *any* 3-terminal voltage regulator "low dropout", even when they had 1.5V or 2V dropout voltages.  This means that you need to scrutinize data sheets (fortunately, they usually list "dropout voltage" or "drop out voltage", so you can do a text search).

A 3.3V regulator with a 0.2V dropout voltage will give you a solid 3.3V until your battery voltage has sagged to 3.5V, at which point it'll give you (battery voltage) - 0.2V.  That's going to be much more satisfactory than a diode.

Comment: That sounds great than you.

Comment: Do you think that this will do it    https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/LD1117DT33-3-3V-Low-Dropout-Voltage-Regulator/233478663934?_trkparms=aid%3D111001%26algo%3DREC.SEED%26ao%3D1%26asc%3D20160908105057%26meid%3D462ef7e4bb2a4e409a0fd2eb26641c15%26pid%3D100675%26rk%3D1%26rkt%3D15%26mehot%3Dnone%26sd%3D233478663934%26itm%3D233478663934%26pmt%3D0%26noa%3D1%26pg%3D2380057%26brand%3DSTMicroelectronics&_trksid=p2380057.c100675.m4236&_trkparms=pageci%3Adbb762cf-72ce-11eb-89fc-32e843a4f227%7Cparentrq%3Abb1ad5611770ad33f84f08f2ffe5887a%7Ciid%3A1

Comment: @Chas The 1117 series chips require about 1.0 to 1.25V overhead to regulate properly.  I'd look for an LDO that only needs 0.2V.  Check digikey, they have great interface for searching by parameters.

Comment: As I said: the phrase "low dropout" doesn't mean anything in advertising literature...

Comment: Ok thanks very much for your help. I passed A Level Physics about 58 years ago and I now have very very little knowledge of this subject.I will have to see what I can find.

Comment: If you're in the UK, I suggest Farnell for a distributor.  Or if DigiKey will talk to you, use them to find the part, then order it locally.

Comment: The best I could manage to get (without a large min. order) was a drop out of 0.5 Now fitted inside my radio and works really well, so thanks very much for all help, I am now getting quite interested in electronics!!